# Influence of design on corrosion control

Tags: materials, design, material-science, corrosion

In "Ahmad. (2006). *Principles of corrosion engineering and corrosion control* (1st ed.). Elsevier/BH.", it is stated that to fight against metallic corrosion it is more convenient to design (C) than design (A).

[image]

[image]

From the explanation provided in the book, I assume that it may be due to a possible accumulation of impurities leading to the establishment of a differential aeration stack and consequently to corrosion. However, I am not able to understand why in the first design, denoted as (A), more such impurities accumulate.

Comment: I'm not sure what the mystery is. (A) just causes the reactants necessary for corrosion to accumulate better. Wet steel rusts. Dry steel doesn't. Same with galvanic corrosion.

Comment: So, design (A) should be avoided because it tends to accumulate more water, which is equivalent to an increase in the corrosion rate. Is that so? @DKNguyen

Comment: Yes. If water was viscous and sticky so it couldn't drain away and also never dried out it wouldn't make that much of a difference. But water does dry out and does drain away. So when it's pooled up like in (A) it has less surface area to evaporate from so it remains in contact with the metal a lot longer.

Comment: So, a possible way to improve the design would be to increase the area where the water falls? @DKNguyen

Comment: If you spread the same volume of water over a larger area, it has more surface area to evaporate from. So a flat roof (and I mean machine-shop flat) will do better than (A). If you make it sloped so it can also drain away, it can get rid of excess water even better and now only the water held onto the surface via surface tension needs to evaporate.

Comment: Thank you very much. It has been a great help to me. @DKNguyen

Answer (score 5):

A is worse because the item holds water.  Holding water resuults in corrosion, certainly near the surface.  C sheds water so it will normally be dry.

Accumulation of impurities seems a needlessly complicated explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Any geometry that can trap water can accelerate corrosion drastically. moisture will act as an electrolyte in reaction cells between the air's oxygen and surface electrons of the metal, leading to rust.

The C type in your figure encourages the shedding of the water which is an essential component of rusting.

> Water, for example is made of an oxygen atom with 6 outer electrons and 2 hydrogen atoms that have 1 electron each. Through the borrowing and sharing of electrons in a reduction reaction, FeO(OH) (the most common form of rust) is created.

[source](https://capitalsteel.net/blog/why-does-steel-rust-plus-other-steel-rusting-questions-answered)